# nginx make root of domain go to subfolder

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I think that what I'm trying to acomplish is similar to question ([https://serverfault.com/questions/232051/rewrite-a-subdirectory-to-root-on-nginx#*=*](https://serverfault.com/questions/232051/rewrite-a-subdirectory-to-root-on-nginx#_=_)) but I'll try to explain it better

so what I'm trying to do it to have the root of the domain (example.com) rewrite to the example.com/curr folder, except when curr is already in the request

example1:

> example.com/ should rewrite to example.com/curr/
>
> leading to the index.php located in there, serving it up (using php5-fpm for php)

example2:

> example.com/curr should just be passed along, to be able to serve up the files

example3:

> example.com/app should also just go to it's directory

current code (not working, 500 ISE):

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ v1/$uri/ /curr/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

#location ~* ^/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ {
#   root /webroot/www/myfolder/;
#   try_files /curr/$1;
#}

location ^~ /p/ {
  rewrite ^/(.*)$ /curr/index.php?p=$1 last;
}
```

note: the last location here defines rewrite if a page is defined, this one works fine and should have a very similar syntax to what should work for the root dir

thanks for helping me out.

update:
I've since also tried

```
location / {
  try_files @missing;
}

location /curr/{
  try_files $uri $uri/;
}

location @missing {
  rewrite ^ /curr/index.php?q=$request_uri&$args?;
}
```

according to the linked question something like this should work, but this just gives me the index page on root

Edit:
I want to do this because all my subdomain folders are in the web/ folder, and I don't want those in the main website folder. I like to have everything separate & still conveniently accessible from f.e. FTP

Edit2:

I've got it up to the point where everything works, except 'example.com', which still renders me a 500 error

Code:

```
location / { rewrite ^ /curr/$uri last; }
location = / { rewrite ^ /curr/ last; }

location ^~ /curr/ {
  try_files $uri $uri/;
}
```

(please also note that using only `location = / { rewrite ^ /curr/ last; }` it did render the homepage correctly (but not everything else))

Comment: You forgot to say _why_ you are trying to do this. This looks quite unusual, and it shouldn't really be necessary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
  location / {
     rewrite ^ /curr/ last;
  }
```

Edit after discussion below:

```
#Default is to rewrite
location / { 
    rewrite ^ /curr$uri last; 
}

#Except if request already begins with curr...
location ^~ /curr/ {

}

#...OR it has a directory already (/curr/ will have matched above)
location ~ /(.*)/(.*) {

}
```

I am not convinced this is the best way to achieve whatever it is you're trying to achieve, but I think it should answer your question.

try_files won't achieve what you want I don't think (and not at all in your example as it's sending you into an infinite loop), as if index.html existed in the root, it wouldn't redirect you to /curr/ it would load up the index.html in root.

Comment: I've tried something similar already, this one is also giving me internal server error (500)
edit: I've tried combining it with:
`location ^~ /v1/ {
  try_files   $uri $uri/;
}`
still renders 500 (and yes it's correctly in there)

Comment: Sorry it should have been `location = / { rewrite ^ /curr/ last; }`

Comment: that did work for index (finally) but if I try to go to f.e.:

example.com/js/something.js then it gives me a 404 not found

edit: that's what the = is for right? (exact match => go to it)

Comment: Yes, exact match.  the /js/something.js shouldn't be written, you might want a location block for everything else though with your directives in there.

Comment: I did that, see original answer for current location blocks

Comment: You have infinite loops.  I am not sure what you are trying to achieve any more, where should /app go exactly, /curr/app or just /app ?

Comment: I did that, see original answer for current location blocks
note: what I'm trying to do is have everything (except exceptions I put in) just go to v1/location, not just /
thanks

Comment: Your current blocks do not reflect mine.  You're still using try_files and sending it into an infinite loop.  My edited answer works fine on my setup.

Comment: I think the problem is the php-processing, I failed to see the obvious since I didn't had issues with static files after a couple of the edits, but now it just gives me a 'download' when I try to go to anything that should load a .php

Comment: You need to add location blocks for PHP in there too then, e.g. /exception/.*\.php and so on